# jQuery: Calling a method inside an event listener only results in the right behavior every other time

Tags: jquery

In my mini application I built a feature area whose visibility can be toggled. The application also contains a couple of links. As I wanted the toggle functionality to only work once one of the links is clicked, I allow it only if one of the links has the class `active`. Now however I have the problem that it only works if I call the method `viewFeature.toggleFeature` inside the EventListener twice. Otherwise the toggling is only successful for every other link (see snippet).

Can you tell me why this is? Where did I mess up?

```js
// _____ MODEL _____  //

let model = {
  linkList: ['Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3', 'Link4', 'Link5'],
  currentLink: undefined,
};


// _____ CONTROLLER _____  //

let controller = {
  getLinks: function() {
    return model.linkList;
  },
  getCurrentLink: function() {
    return model.currentLink;
  },
  init: function() {
    viewList.init();
  }
};

// _____ VIEW _____  //

let viewList = {
  init: function() {
    $.each(controller.getLinks(), function(index) {
      $('.link-list').append('<p class="link-name link-name-' + index + '">' + controller.getLinks()[index] + '</p>');

      $('.link-name-' + index).click(function(e) {
        //viewFeature.toggleFeature();
        $('.link-name').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        viewFeature.toggleFeature();
      });
    });
  }
};

// _____ VIEW (FEATURE) _____  //

let viewFeature = {
  toggleFeature: function() {
    if ($('.active').length) {
      $('.feature-btn').click(function(e) {
        $('.feature-wrap').toggleClass('visible');
      });
    }
  }
};

controller.init();
```

```css
.link-name {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.link-name.active {
  color: green;
}

.feature-btn {
  width: 100%;
}

.feature-wrap {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.feature-wrap.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-list">
</div>

<div class="feature-area">
  <button class="btn feature-btn">Features</button>
  <div class="feature-wrap">
    <div class="input-wrap name">
      <label for="input-name" class="label-name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-name">
    </div>
    <button class="btn save-btn">Save</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am not able to get what issue are you having here. Please elaborate more.

Comment: The method viewFeature.toggleFeature is only called once the first link was clicked. Otherwise it is blocked, this is what I need. However the problem I have with this is that now it only works to toggle the features every other time when I click a different link. Otherwise it is blocked and nothing happens. I wonder why this is because I call viewFeature.toggleFeature every time when a link is clicked.

Comment: Do you know how to debug code by adding lots of `debugger` in js code at required places and then opening the browser console and then reloading the page again?

Comment: I haven't used it before as I'm quite new to JS but I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: There are so many youtube videos on how to debug js code using the debugger keyword. Please check them out. It will help you a lot in learning.

Comment: I got help for this issue and it turned out that I had a logical error in my code. The problem was that I called `viewFeature.toggleFeature` (which puts an event listener on the toggle button) many times instead of only calling it once when the application is rendered.